# How can I create my own defined MTD device through kernel command line on ARM system?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, flash-memory

At first, I didn't add any kernel parameter and then got MTD device

```
/proc/mtd:
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 01000000 00010000 "spi1.0"
```

then, I added `setenv mtdids "mtdids=spi1.0"`, and
`setenv mtdparts "mtdparts=spi1.0:2m(U-Boot)ro,-(RootFS)ro"` to kernel command line, at the meantime, I turned on

```
"Command line partition table parsing",
"ARM Firmware Suite partition parsing"
```

of Device Drivers ---> Memory Technology Device (MTD) support through Kconfig.
Finally, I got,

```
 dev:    size   erasesize  name
 mtd0: 00100000 00010000 "u-boot"
 mtd1: 00400000 00010000 "kernel"
 mtd2: 00a00000 00010000 "rootfs"
```

But this is still not what I want.
Do I have something missing?
Thanks for help,

Comment: Please give the software versions you are using.  It is also possible through the device tree.

Comment: @peter, the uboot version is 2013.01 and linux kernel is 4.4.36.

Answer (score 0):

you can work with it but after creating the partitions you must create an ubifs file system for the each partitions, then only the board will work with the MTD.